# Styling the unselectedItemTintColor UITabBar with iOS 15

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm having trouble setting the `tabbar.unselectedItemTintColor`. There is some weird conflict when I try to set both the `unselectedItemTintColor` and the `scrollEdgeAppearance`.

I can run this code and things work as expected:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
tabBarController.delegate = self;
tabBar.translucent = NO;

UITabBar.appearance.shadowImage = [self colorForTabBar:[UIColor darkGrayColor]]; //this is the color of the seperator line at the top.
UITabBar.appearance.unselectedItemTintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
UIColor *tintColor =  [UIColor greenColor];

tabBar.barTintColor =  tintColor;
tabBar.backgroundImage = [self colorForTabBar:tintColor];
```

The unselected items are purple, and the background is green. The problem is that if I scroll down to the bottom of my view controller then the `scrollEdgeAppearance` is shown instead of the default, and the green color goes transparent, and my shadowImage disappears. To combat this, I have tried setting:

```
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
    tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBar.standardAppearance;
}
```

And that makes everything turn gray! Even the standard default appearance turns gray.

I have played around with trying set all the appearance parameters like this:

```
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
    UITabBarAppearance *appearance = [UITabBarAppearance new];
    [appearance configureWithOpaqueBackground];
    appearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    appearance.shadowImage = [self colorForTabBar:[UIColor darkGrayColor]]; //this is the color of the seperator line at the top.

    tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    
    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
    tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
}
```

And that almost works except the `tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor` isn't working, and all my icons are gray instead of purple.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this same issue.  Try adding this after the "appearance.shadowImage =" line:

```
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = 
@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor purpleColor] };
```